# R - Trying to loop over a folder and subfolders, and save files info into a table

Tags: r, file, for-loop, rstudio, directory

I'm trying to loop over a folder and its subfolders, and save all the files info (size, mdate, etc) into a table.
I wrote the code below, but it isn't working like I've planned, since I'm getting 'folder/filename' as filename and 'main folder' as folder in every line.
Could anybody help me?
Thank you.

```
########################################################
########################################################
# Example:                                             #
# The path 'c:/test' contains 1 file and 3 subfolders  #
# with 2 files in each -> 7 file in total              #
#
# c:/test
#       file_000.txt
#
#       + subfolder1
#                   + file_001.docx
#                   + file_002.txt
#       + subfolder2
#                   + file_003.docx
#                   + file_004.bmp
#       + subfolder3
#                   + file_005.xlsx
#                   + file_006.txt
########################################################

# Create the empty dataframe 'table'
table = data.frame()

# Set the working path
path = 'c:/test'

# List all folders and subfolders in path
folders_list = list.dirs(path, recursive = TRUE)

# Start looping in folders
for(folder in folders_list){
    setwd(folder)
    dir = getwd()

    # Get files list in each folder
    files_list = list.files(folder, recursive = TRUE)

    # Start looping in files
    for(file in files_list){

        # Get info about each file and append below the previous line in the dataframe 'table'
        table = rbind(table, file.info(file))

  }
    # Add a column withe the file name to each line in 'table'
    table$file = row.names(file)

    # Try to add the folder path to another column 'folder'
    table$folder = dir
}
# Show 'table'
View(table)



##############################################
# RESULT (head(table)):
#                          size isdir mode               mtime               ctime               atime exe  folder
# file_000.txt                0 FALSE  666 2016-10-27 17:19:40 2016-10-27 17:19:40 2016-10-27 17:19:40  no c:/test
# subfolder1/file_001.docx    0 FALSE  666 2016-10-27 17:57:00 2016-10-27 17:57:00 2016-10-27 17:57:00  no c:/test
# subfolder1/file_002.txt     0 FALSE  666 2016-10-27 17:18:34 2016-10-27 17:18:34 2016-10-27 17:18:34  no c:/test
# subfolder2/file_003.docx    0 FALSE  666 2016-10-27 17:57:29 2016-10-27 17:57:29 2016-10-27 17:57:29  no c:/test
# subfolder2/file_004.bmp     0 FALSE  666 2016-10-27 17:19:00 2016-10-27 17:19:00 2016-10-27 17:19:00  no c:/test
# subfolder3/file_005.xlsx 8081 FALSE  666 2016-10-27 17:57:52 2016-10-27 17:57:52 2016-10-27 17:57:52  no c:/test
##############################################

##############################################
# NEEDED:
#                          size isdir mode               mtime               ctime               atime exe  folder
# file_000.txt                0 FALSE  666 2016-10-27 17:19:40 2016-10-27 17:19:40 2016-10-27 17:19:40  no c:/test
# file_001.docx               0 FALSE  666 2016-10-27 17:57:00 2016-10-27 17:57:00 2016-10-27 17:57:00  no c:/test/subfolder1
# file_002.txt                0 FALSE  666 2016-10-27 17:18:34 2016-10-27 17:18:34 2016-10-27 17:18:34  no c:/test/subfolder1
# file_003.docx               0 FALSE  666 2016-10-27 17:57:29 2016-10-27 17:57:29 2016-10-27 17:57:29  no c:/test/subfolder2
# file_004.bmp                0 FALSE  666 2016-10-27 17:19:00 2016-10-27 17:19:00 2016-10-27 17:19:00  no c:/test/subfolder2
# file_005.xlsx            8081 FALSE  666 2016-10-27 17:57:52 2016-10-27 17:57:52 2016-10-27 17:57:52  no c:/test/subfolder3
##############################################
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
files     <- list.files("test", full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)
file_info <- lapply(files, file.info)
table     <- do.call(rbind, file_info)

table$file   <- gsub(".*/(.+)$", "\\1", rownames(table))
table$folder <- gsub("(.*)/.+$", "\\1", rownames(table))
```